# Connect void to action?

Tags: objective-c

I just started to learn objective-c and one thing is not clear for me

Ok i have a button in InterFace Builder. I my .h file i have the code;

```
- (void)startButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

How i can `'link'` the `'void'` to my button to do the action?

Code here is not working how do i need to do that?

```
    - (void)startButtonPressed:(id)sender { 

//Some stuff in here

    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBAction`, in fact, is `void`

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?IBAction

```
// from <AppKit/NSNibDeclarations.h>
#ifndef IBAction
    #define IBAction void
#endif
```

It is given so, you won't mess up actions coming from UI and functions of your class implementation.

To create function connectable with UI, you need to set its type to `IBAction`

```
// .h
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender;
// .m
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender { 
   //Some stuff in here
}
```

which is coorect, as well as

```
// .m
- (void)startButtonPressed:(id)sender { 
   //Some stuff in here
}
```

The type in implementation, can be `void` directly

Comment: I did; `- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender;` but i can't connect the button to the action? in Interface Builder?

Comment: means you see the action in IB and can't connect, or you don't even see it?

Answer (score 2):

Change the return value in the header file (the *.h* file) to `IBAction` instead of `void`. So, they would look like this:

```
// .h header file
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender;

// .m implementation file
- (void)startButtonPressed:(id)sender { /* do some work */ }
```

The `IBAction` type is exactly the same to the compiler as `void`. It's used by Interface Builder which parses the header file to see what it can link up. When you set the return type to `IBAction`, you're telling interface builder that an action can be linked to this method implementation (and now you will be able to draw the connection in IB).

Because `void` and `IBAction` are the same, you could use `IBAction` in your implementation file as well for the return type, although this is not commonly done. Also, since an `IBAction` and `void` are the same, you can only create actions that do not return any value (i.e., the return of an action method *must* be `void`).

Answer (score 1):

Interface builder needs the method tagged with `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Interface Builder needs the interface to be tagged with `IBAction`, not the implementation.

Comment: @JasonCoco thanks for the correction. I usually tag both - I did not know that tagging only `.h` was sufficient.

Comment: @bbum Good to know. Starting with which version of IB? Xcode 4?